# powershell: Count Down Timer

Tags: powershell, datetime

Hello I am new to powershell.

I am trying to run this script from start-up in order to have a pre-configured timer for an exam when system boots up

**Requirement:
Grab today's date and display how many hours left from due date**

I'm using this PowerShell code example I found:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$script:Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$script:Label.AutoSize = $true
$script:Form.Controls.Add($Label)
$Timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$Timer.Interval = 1000
$script:CountDown = 60
$Timer.add_Tick(
    {
        $script:Label.Text = "Your exam will end in $CountDown hrs"
        $script:CountDown--
    }
)
$script:Timer.Start()
$script:Form.ShowDialog()
```

I am trying to format also to have display as

```
$clock = Get-Date $myDateTime  -Format HH:mm:ss.fff
```

But it only grabs by seconds, how can I do a count down by datetime or -Format HH:mm:ss.fff

Comment: So what's the issue

Comment: You are not giving a time scope/format to start with. Countdown times have been a thing in many languages for decades. There are many pre-built countdown times all over the web, in many languages, including PowerShell. So, no reason to start from scratch on this, or struggle over it. [Just search for one or more of them](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+countdown+timer+form%27&t=h_&ia=web).

Answer (score 0):

I added a due date/time from which the code subtracts the current date/time and then formats the timespan value in dd days hh:mm:ss format.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$DueDate = Get-Date -Date "4/4/2021" -Hour 17 #Due Date/Time!

$Form  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Width   = "500"
$Form.Height  = "100"
$lblCountDown = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblCountDown.AutoSize = $true
$lblCountDown.Font = "Century, 15"
$lblCountDown.Text =    
  "Your exam will end in: {0:dd} days {0:hh}:{0:mm}:{0:ss}" -f 
  ($DueDate - (Get-Date))

$Form.Controls.Add($lblCountDown)
$tmrCountdown = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$tmrCountdown.Interval = 1000
$tmrCountdown.add_Tick(
 {
  $lblCountDown.Text = 
    "Your exam will end in: {0:dd} days {0:hh}:{0:mm}:{0:ss}" -f 
     ($DueDate - (Get-Date))
 }
)

$tmrCountdown.Start()
$Form.ShowDialog()
$tmrCountdown.Dispose()
Remove-Variable tmrCountdown
```

[image]

Of course, if you don't want the days display just remove the formatting parameter from the string.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

***Don't write UX/UI/GUI, if you don't have to.***

just use what is on your box first, for example, your browser, Well, IE in this use case.

```
function Show-CountDownInWebPage
{
    [cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    [Alias('scdw')]
    Param
    (
        [datetime]$TargetDate
    ) 

    $ie = New-Object -comobject "InternetExplorer.Application"
    $ie.navigate("about:blank")

    $ie.top     = 10
    $ie.left    = 10
    $ie.height  = 120
    $ie.width   = 260
    $ie.toolbar = $false
    $ie.visible = $true

    $body       = $script:ie.document.body.innerhtml

    while ((Get-Date) -le $TargetDate)
    {
        $TimeLeft                   = New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date) -End $TargetDate
        $body                       = "Time left to: $TargetDate<br> Hours: $($TimeLeft.hours) Minutes:$($TimeLeft.minutes) Seconds: $($TimeLeft.Seconds)"
        $ie.document.body.innerhtml = $body

        Start-Sleep 0.5
    }

    #Beep twice at the end.
    [console]::beep(600,400)
    [console]::beep(600,400)
}

Show-CountDownInWebPage -TargetDate (Get-Date).AddMinutes(1)
```

***Update***

Or as per my comment to RetiredGeek, just use the PS consolehost directly. Just, save the below as Start-ExamClock.ps1, or whatever name you choose.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait((Get-Date).AddDays(3))
[DateTime]$ExamDate = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Days unitl exam. Enter accept the default or modify.')

Clear-Host

while ((Get-Date) -le $ExamDate)
{
    $TimeLeft = New-TimeSpan -Start $(Get-Date) -End $ExamDate
    "
    Exam Due in : $ExamDate 
    Days        : $($TimeLeft.Days) 
    Hours       : $($TimeLeft.hours) 
    Minutes     : $($TimeLeft.minutes) 
    Seconds     : $($TimeLeft.Seconds)
    " | 
    Out-Host

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

    Clear-Host
}
[console]::beep(600,400)
[console]::beep(600,400)
```

Runs this way - you can create a shortcut to fire this off or use a scheduled task.

```
.\Start-ExamClock.ps1
```

Prompt to respond to. Just backspace and overwrite.

```
Days until the exam. Enter accept the default or modify.: 04/05/2021 14:00:00

# Results - in a normal PowerShell console host window
<#
Exam Due in : 04/06/2021 14:00:00
Days        : 3
Hours       : 10
Minutes     : 7
Seconds     : 8
#>
```

Of course, as long as the console is running, it will update. If you find yourself in the consolehost/Windows Terminal/ISE/VSCode, you can just add this to your title bar, along with whatever else you may have there, or set this as a custom prompt.

If you really need/want to write a UX/UI/GUI, then cool and all, but be sure to get ramped upon proper and industry best practices on that topic first, and know that, that path, has nothing to do with Powershell at all.

Youtube is your friend.

> 'Windows UX/UI Best Practices:
> https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Windows+UX%2FUI+best+practice

Comment: Good idea in theory. However, assuming that someone has something on their box is not. Personally, I have IE disabled on my machine (security hole) so the script only produces errors. Where as since the OP is writing PS why not keep everything in PS since it is a base requirement? Not trying to start a flame war here just making an observation.

Comment: Choices, choices, choices.... One could still avoid all the form stuff just by popping the consolehost or in the PowerShell Title bar of an existing instance, for the same thing. After 4+decads in the field, I a firm believer in, 'don't increase your workload unnecessarily, use what is there before skewing off.' Yet, as a `soon-to-be` retried geek (if I can't find something new to do with my current employer), it's just two old folks, just exchanging/sharing experiences/ideas/concepts for those potentially young whippersnappers in the pipe..  ***;-}***

Comment: Amen to that! Here's wishing you well on your retirement, you'll love it! Been doing it for 21 years now and don't know how I ever found time to work!

Comment: Thx and Roger that, big time. Office politics/unneeded meetings, argh!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution...and it's simple, because simple is best in scripting

```
"Waiting 1 minute"
$i=60
while ($i -gt 0){
    write-host -nonewline $i
    sleep 1
    $i--
    cls
}
```